# Actualizar datos dentro de un Div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, leaflet

Hola soy nuevo en javascript, lo que quiero hacer es que el contenido de un `div` se actualice cada vez que esta cambie.

Los datos provienen de un archivo geoJson y los llamo a través de Ajax.
Este es el código:

```
var nivel_actual = 0;
function desplegarAlerta() {
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: "js/puntos.json",
   success: function (data) {
              // creo leyenda
              div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend alert');
              labelPuntos = ['<strong style="margin-left: 5px;">Puntos Alerta</strong> 
                            <hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 5px;">'];

  var datos = data.features;
  datos.forEach(function (datos) {

    nivel = datos.properties.nivel;
    var nombre = datos.properties.punto;

    legend2 = L.control({ position: 'bottomright' });
    legend2.onAdd = function () {

      // condicional contenido div
      if (nivel == 1) {
        div.innerHTML +=
          labelPuntos.push(
            '<p style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <strong>Nombre: </strong>' + nombre + '</p>' + '<p style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <strong>Nivel de Alerta: </strong>' + nivel + '</p>' + '<hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin- bottom: 0px;">');
           }

      div.innerHTML = labelPuntos.join('<br>');
      return div;
    };
    legend2.addTo(map);
  });

  if (nivel == 0) {
    div.innerHTML +=
      labelPuntos.push(
        '<p> ' + 'Sin Riesgo' + '</p> ');
  }
  L.DomEvent.on(div, 'mousewheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
  div.innerHTML = labelPuntos.join('<br>');
  return div;
  }
 });
}

function refrescaAlerta() {
// desplegarAlerta();
$.ajax({
     url: "js/puntos.json",
     dataType: 'json'
}).then(function (response) {
 var data = response.features;
 data.forEach(function (data) {

   // sólo lo ejecutas si cambió
   if (data.properties.nivel != nivel_actual) {
     nivel_actual = data.properties.nivel;
     desplegarAlerta();
   }
 });
  window.setTimeout(refrescaAlerta, 30000);
 });
}
refrescaAlerta();
```

El `div` solo se actualiza si hay cambio en la variable nivel, el problema es que actualmente lo duplica en lugar de solo reemplazarlo.

EDIT: Si uso `$(".alert").load(' .alert');` refresca el `div` pero lo devuelve  vacío, sin la información dentro.

Comment: Finalmente llegué con ayuda de la comunidad a esta solución https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329157/setinterval-duplica-leyenda-en-cada-intervalo/329256#329256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios innerHTML, no se cual sea el de tu problema pero en definitiva es causado por el signo +

```
div.innerHTML +=
      labelPuntos.push(
        '<p> ' + 'Sin Riesgo' + '</p> ');
```

eso lo que hace es concatenar el contenido actual con lo que están enviando

debería ser

```
div.innerHTML = 'nuevo contenido';
```