# setInterval duplica leyenda en cada intervalo

Tags: javascript, leaflet

estoy creando una leyenda en `leaflet`, necesito que esta leyenda se actualice cada 30 seg ya que los datos en su interior y que vienen de un archivo `geoJson` se actualizan todo el tiempo.

El problema que se me presenta es que el intervalo `setInterval` al actualizar duplica la leyenda, es decir, despues de un minuto tengo 2 leyendas, quisiera saber como puedo eliminar o actualizar la leyenda anterior.

Este es mi código:

```
window.onload = function () {
  $.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: "js/puntos.json",
   success: function (data) {
  // creo leyenda
    div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend alert');
    labelPuntos = ['<strong style="margin-left: 5px;">Puntos en Alerta</strong><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 5px;">'];

  var datos = data.features;
  datos.forEach(function (datos) {

    nivel = datos.properties.nivel;
    nombre = datos.properties.punto;

    legend2 = L.control({ position: 'bottomright'});
    legend2.onAdd = function () {

      // condicional contenido div
      if (nivel == 1) {
        div.innerHTML =
          labelPuntos.push(
            '<p id="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <strong>Nombre: </strong>' + nombre + '</p>' + '<p id="alert2" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <strong>Nivel de Alerta: </strong>' + nivel + '</p>' + '<hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">');
          }

          div.innerHTML = labelPuntos.join('<br>');
          return div;
        };
        legend2.addTo(map);
  });

  if (nivel == 0) {
    div.innerHTML =
      labelPuntos.push(
        '<p> ' + 'Sin Riesgo' + '</p> ');
  }
  L.DomEvent.on(div, 'mousewheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
  div.innerHTML = labelPuntos.join('<br>');
  return div;
 }
});
}
setInterval("window.onload();", 30000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Asigna ID a la leyenda y verifica si existe, para actualizar o crear.

Comment: Como puedo agregarle un ID al div de la leyenda si la crea en L.DomUtil.create?, si le intento agregar el ID genera error en la creación de la leyenda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asignando ID a la leyenda y verificando que existe:

```
window.onload = function () {
  $.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: "js/puntos.json",
   success: function (data) {
      // Buscar por ID
      div = document.getElementById('leyenda');
      // Verificar si existe
      if(!div) {
         // creo leyenda
         div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend alert');
      }
    labelPuntos = ['<strong style="margin-left: 5px;">Puntos en Alerta</strong><hr style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 5px;">'];

  var datos = data.features;
  datos.forEach(function (datos) {

    nivel = datos.properties.nivel;
    nombre = datos.properties.punto;

    legend2 = L.control({ position: 'bottomright'});
    legend2.onAdd = function () {

      // En este punto, sabemos que el div ya existe, 
      // Asignar ID para no volver a crearlo
      div.id = 'leyenda';
      // condicional contenido div
      if (nivel == 1) {
        div.innerHTML =
          labelPuntos.push(
            '<p id="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <strong>Nombre: </strong>' + nombre + '</p>' + '<p id="alert2" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <strong>Nivel de Alerta: </strong>' + nivel + '</p>' + '<hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">');
          }

          div.innerHTML = labelPuntos.join('<br>');
          return div;
        };
        legend2.addTo(map);
  });

  if (nivel == 0) {
    div.innerHTML =
      labelPuntos.push(
        '<p> ' + 'Sin Riesgo' + '</p> ');
  }
  L.DomEvent.on(div, 'mousewheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
  div.innerHTML = labelPuntos.join('<br>');
  return div;
 }
});
}
setInterval("window.onload();", 30000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```